# Laravel 5 Vue hot module replacement (HMR)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, vue.js, webpack-hmr

My Vue HOT MODULE REPLACEMENT (HMR) not working. What I have and what I do:

- local server on http:\db7\ on port 80 on Windows 10 (xampp with php 7.2.6)
- laravel latest version with `composer install` and `npm install`
- next package.json: 

  `{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "npm run development",
  "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
  "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "prod": "npm run production",
  "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "live": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.18",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
  "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2",
  "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.10",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
  "vue": "^2.5.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "ajv": "^6.5.1",
  "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
  "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "vue-flatpickr-component": "^7.0.4",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
  "vue-snotify": "^3.1.0",
  "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  }
  }`
- in laravel template (blade) I have `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>` and when I opening page and look page code I see `<script src="//localhost:8080//js/app.js"></script>`. When `npm run hot` I can see my js if open `localhost:8080//js/app.js` manualy from browser. I'm try write url manualy in template too - `<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/bundle.js"></script>`. The same result.
- When `npm run hot` NOT runing `netstat -ano | findstr 8080` in cmd clear - so, the 8080 port is not using. When `npm run hot`is runing - 8080 is LISTENING.
- When I run `npm run hot` and reload page with appliccation in console no any messages like "HMR is running" and e.t.c.
- When I do any changes in my Vue components I see, that "Compiled successfully" in my PHPStorm console, but in browser no any changes. And more - there are no any changes, if I reload page with ctrl+f5 or open page in chrome incognito mode. There are no any changes in app.js if I reopen `localhost:8080//js/app.js` in browser manualy too.
- My `webpack.mix.js` in laravel root folder:

  let mix = require('laravel-mix');

  mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
      .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

Step by step:

1. Install fresh laravel `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`
2. `npm i`
3. `npm run dev`
4. Open `resources\views\welcome.blade.php` remove all between `<body></body>` and add next (see on the bottom)
5. Check in chrome `http://blog/public/`. I can see 'Example Component'.
6. Open chrome DevTools on page and open console in it.
7. In cmd on project folder run `npm run hot` and wait for compiling
8. Hard reload page on chrome (ctrl+f5). In console I [see only next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7huhZ.png). No HRM.
9. Try to change vue component. In `resources\assets\js\components\ExampleComponent.vue` add any symbol to html code in template and check chrome page - no any chages. Hard reload page - no any changes!
10. I do not do more than described above

Code for #4

```
<div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>
</div>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Help my please!

Comment: The HMR functionality should run with websockets, have you tried inspecting the websocket connection data in your network tab to see if anything is going wrong there?

Comment: @Stephan-v there are no any activity on WS (DevTools->Network->WS). Yes - I reload page

Comment: Perhaps this can help out: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1483#issuecomment-366685986 It seems to be broken at the moment.

Comment: @Stephan-v IT WORKS!!! Thanks! Will you create answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the hot module replacement functionality is currently bugged. This is a temporary workaround but this does not solve issues like CSS reloading:

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1483#issuecomment-366685986

We will have to wait for a proper fix.